# How to find min value of multidimensional dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict like this and I want to find minimum value:

```
fault = {
        'A': {
            'X': {
                10: 0.34,
                12: 0.32,
                15: 1.53,
                ...
                43: 0.2314
            },
            'Y': {
                10: 0.12,     <--- Min
                12: 0.32,
                15: 0.3214,
                ...
                43: 1.4
            }
        },
        'B': {
            'X': {...},
            'Y': {...}
        },
        'C': {
            'X': {...},
            'Y': {...}
        },
        'D': {
            'A': {...},
            'T': {...}
        },
        ...
        'Z': {...}
    }
```

How can I find minimum value of inner dict with keys?
Expected output is something like that:

```
('A', ('Y', {10: 0.12}))
```

or

```
['A', 'Y', 10, 0.12]
```

> It doesn't matter which data type output is as long as it gives the desired
>
> Note: Nested dicts have same length

Comment: Do you have equally many levels of nesting everywhere?

Comment: Yes. All lens of nested dicts are same

Comment: Why that funky nesting as expected output? Wouldn't `['A', 'Y', 10, 0.12]` make more sense?

Comment: Flatten your dict using https://github.com/ianlini/flatten-dict and then just use `min(flattened_dict, key=lambda x: flattened_dict[x])`

Comment: I just showed it as an example, I'm expecting 'A', 'Y', 10 and 0.12. It doesn't matter which data type output is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
def d_min(d, c = []):
   if all(not isinstance(i, dict) for i in d.values()):
     _m = min(d.values())
     yield (c, {a:b for a, b in d.items() if b == _m}, _m)
   else:
     yield from [i for a, b in d.items() for i in d_min(b, c+[a])]

def to_tuple(d, v):
  return (d[0], v if not d[1:] else to_tuple(d[1:], v))

p, result, _ = min(d_min(fault), key=lambda x:x[-1])
print(to_tuple(p, result))
```

Output:

```
('A', ('Y', {10: 0.12}))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a generator expresion with the built-in function `min`:

```
min(((i, (k0, (k1, {k2: i}) )) 
    for k0, d in fault.items()
    for k1, v in d.items()
    for k2, i in v.items()), key=lambda x: x[0])[1]
```

output:

```
('A', ('Y', {10: 0.12}))
```

---

if you hav

Comment: This will fail when there are multiple innermost keys with the same minimum value because `dict` objects are not comparable. See demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/ShallowSinfulAdministrator

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the `min` function with list iterators:

```
min([min([min(dd.values()) for dd in d.values()]) for d in fault.values()])
```

Not a general solution for arbitrary depths.

Comment: you will not get the expected output :)

Answer (score 0):

General recursive solution:

```
array = {
    'A': {
        'X': {
            10: 0.34,
            12: 0.32,
            15: 1.53,
            43: 0.2314,
        },
        'Y': {
            10: 0.12,
            12: 0.32,
            15: 0.3214,
            43: 1.4
        }
    },
}

def find_min(elem):
    current_min = None
    if isinstance(elem, dict):
        for key, values in elem.items():
            m = find_min(values)
            if not current_min or m < current_min:
                current_min = m
    elif isinstance(elem, list):
        for e in elem:
            m = find_min(values)
            if not current_min or m < current_min:
                current_min = m
    else:
        current_min = elem
    return current_min


print(find_min(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to flatten the dictionary structure while retaining the hierarchy of keys corresponding to each value.  Then use the min function on the flattened list and build your nested tuple/dict result from that.

```
K1,K2,K3,V3 = min( (K1,K2,K3,V3) for K1,V1 in fault.items() for K2,V2 in V1 for K3,V3 in V2),key=lambda r:r[-1])

result = (K1,(K2,{K3:V3}))
```

If the number of levels can vary, you will need to create use a recursive function to flatten the dictionary.

```
def flatDict(D):
    for K,V in D.items():
        if isinstance(V,dict):
            for KVn in flatDict(V):
                yield (K,)+KVn
        else:
            yield (K,V)

*keys,lastKey,value = min(flatDict(fault),key=lambda r:r[-1])

result = {lastKey:value}
for key in reversed(keys):
    result = (key,result)
```

*note, your resulting structure of nested tuples is going to be quite challenging to use if the number of levels changes. You might want to consider a simple tuple as returned by flatDict()*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator expression that iterates through the 3 levels of the dict structure and outputs the innermost items in the expected format, and pass it to the `min` function with a key function that returns the value of the innermost dict:

```
min(((k, (s, {i: v})) for k, d in fault.items() for s, m in d.items()
    for i, v in m.items()), key=lambda t: next(iter(t[1][1].values())))
```